# mysqldump all tables with data, with create and add-drop tables statements

Tags: database, mysql

I need to take back up of MySQL database,but condition is that back up file should contains only tables that contains data, and there should be an create and drop statements too.

I checked `mysqldump` manual pages, didn't get options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the tables that contain data, why do you not simply selectively dump those tables?

```
mysqldump [options] [db_name [tbl_name ...]]
```